# Adding a border to 3/4 sides in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add a border to 3/4 sides on a custom button (the bottom has no border). However, the code produces no border anywhere. If I give all the sides a border, it works, but does not work if I do 3/4 sides. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is the code:

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget{
  CustomButton(this.img, this.title, this.connectivity, this.link);

  final img;
  final title;
  final connectivity;
  final link;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UrlViewers(link)));
        print("Link: $link");
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2),
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),

              ),
              border: Border(
                left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                right: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
                
              ),
              image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(img), fit: BoxFit.cover)
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white24,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue earlier, apparently there is no simple way to add borders to a container while controlling its radius..

if you just remove the borderRadius parameter from the BoxDecoration it should work just fine.